# Escape double quotes in a string

Tags: c#, string, double-quotes

Double quotes can be escaped like this:

```
string test = @"He said to me, ""Hello World"". How are you?";
```

But this involves adding character `"` to the string. Is there a C# function or other method to escape double quotes so that no changing in string is required?

Comment: you can use \"Hello World\" like this

Comment: What do you really want as a result? "" becomes " in a literal string.

Comment: A similar question for C/C++ (as this may be the top search engine hit): *[How can I get double quotes into a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338818)*

Comment: Related: *[Can I escape a double quote in a verbatim string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909)*

Answer (score 357, accepted):

Yes, you can escape the `"` using a backslash:

```
string test = "He said to me, \"Hello World\" . How are you?";
```

Otherwise you have to use verbatim string literals as you have.

The string has not changed in either case - there is a single *escaped* `"` in it. This is just a way to tell C# that the character is part of the string and not a string terminator.

Comment: why when using @ does not work using \?

Comment: @toha - because that's how they were defined. A verbatim string literal (@ string) treats a backslash `\\` as nothing more than that. It isn't treated as an escape sequence. It is kind of the point of verbatim string literals.

Answer (score 154):

You can use backslash either way:

```
string str = "He said to me, \"Hello World\". How are you?";
```

It prints:

```
He said to me, "Hello World". How are you?
```

which is exactly the same that is printed with:

```
string str = @"He said to me, ""Hello World"". How are you?";
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/N0eH7v).

`"` is still part of your string.

You can check Jon Skeet's *[Strings in C# and .NET](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Strings)* article for more information.

Answer (score 27):

In C# you can use the backslash to put special characters to your string.
For example, to put `"`, you need to write `\"`.
There are a lot of characters that you write using the backslash:

Backslash with other characters

```
  \0 nul character
  \a Bell (alert)
  \b Backspace
  \f Formfeed
  \n New line
  \r Carriage return
  \t Horizontal tab
  \v Vertical tab
  \' Single quotation mark
  \" Double quotation mark
  \\ Backslash
```

Any character substitution by numbers:

```
  \xh to \xhhhh, or \uhhhh - Unicode character in hexadecimal notation (\x has variable digits, \u has 4 digits)
  \Uhhhhhhhh - Unicode surrogate pair (8 hex digits, 2 characters)
```

Answer (score 19):

Another thing worth mentioning from C# 6 is interpolated strings can be used along with `@`.

Example:

```
string helloWorld = @"""Hello World""";
string test = $"He said to me, {helloWorld}. How are you?";
```

Or

```
string helloWorld = "Hello World";
string test = $@"He said to me, ""{helloWorld}"". How are you?";
```

Check running code [here](https://ideone.com/ovbMcx)!

View the reference to interpolation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)!

Comment: From what C# version is this valid for? Can you provide some references? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67532870/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Note that bouth `$@""` and `@$""` are valids.

Answer (score 16):

C#11 introduces a new feature called "raw string literals." To quote the Microsoft documentation:

> Beginning with C# 11, you can use raw string literals to more easily create strings that are multi-line, or use any characters requiring escape sequences. Raw string literals remove the need to ever use escape sequences. You can write the string, including whitespace formatting, how you want it to appear in output."

SOURCE: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#raw-string-literals

**EXAMPLE:** So using the original example, you could do this (note that raw string literals always begin with three or more quotation marks):

```
string testSingleLine = """He said to me, "Hello World". How are you?""";
string testMultiLine = """
He said to me, "Hello World". How are you?
""";
```

Comment: Would be good to add code snippet to show how raw string literal would represent the question's `He said to me, "Hello World". How are you?`.

Answer (score 8):

You're misunderstanding escaping.

The extra `"` characters are part of the string literal; they are interpreted by the compiler as a **single** `"`.

The actual value of your string is still `He said to me, "Hello World". How are you?`, as you'll see if you print it at runtime.

Answer (score 6):

Please explain your problem. You say:

> But this involves adding character " to the string.

What problem is that? You can't type `string foo = "Foo"bar"";`, because that'll invoke a compile error. As for the **adding** part, in string size terms that is not true:

```
@"""".Length == 1

"\"".Length == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In C#, there are at least four ways to embed a quote within a string:

1. Escape quote with a backslash
2. Precede string with `@` and use double quotes
3. Use the corresponding ASCII character
4. Use the hexadecimal Unicode character

Please refer [this document](http://davidgiard.com/2018/11/02/EmbeddingQuotesWithinACString.aspx) for detailed explanation.

Comment: It would be better if you summarised here (by editing your answer) - as the link may break at any time. E.g., what exactly is meant by *"Use the corresponding ASCII character"*? How exactly is it encoded in source code? You could provide one or more (awesome) code examples for each of the four ways.