# How to define a string like: sss" + str1 + "ddd

Tags: c#, string, verbatim

```
string str1="xxx";
string str2=@"sss" + str1 + "ddd";
Console.WriteLine(str2);
```

The above code gives:

> sssxxxddd

But what I want is:

> sss" + str1 + "ddd

How to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480724/escape-double-quotes-in-string

Comment: @BJMyers - It's a similar question, but not a duplicate.

Comment: To obtain a " within the string itself, you need to write ""

Comment: @宋晓楠 - No, that's not right.

Comment: like this: @"sss"" + str1 + ""ddd"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape the quotes by preceding them with a backslash (`\`).

```
string str1 = "xxx";
string str2 = "sss\" + str1 + \"ddd";
Console.WriteLine(str2);
```

For strings prefixed with the `@` character, quotes are escaped by placing two together (i.e., `string str2 = "sss"" + str1 + ""ddd"`).

Comment: Thanks! the placing two quotes to escape when using @ is exactly what I want to know!

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
 Console.WriteLine("sss\" + str1 + \"ddd");
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Enigmativity I changed the answer, but I think he/she can figure it out with my original answer. I tend not to give direct "copy and paste" answer to questions.

Comment: Yes this works, but I'm more interested in knowing how to do it WITHOUT removing @. My question was not clear enough. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
        string str1 = "xxx";
        string str2 = @"sss"" + str1 + ""ddd";
        Console.WriteLine(str2);

        string str3 = "xxx";
        string str4 = "sss\" + str1 + \"ddd";
        Console.WriteLine(str4);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: The second way does not output `sss" + str1 + "ddd`.

Answer (score -2):

```
string str1="xxx";
string str2=@"sss""" + str1 + @"""ddd";
Console.WriteLine(str2);
```

or

```
string str1="xxx";
string str2="sss\"" + str1 + "\"ddd";
Console.WriteLine(str2);
```

This will give you an answer like: sss"xxx"ddd. If you want an answer like sss" + str1 + "ddd then you replace the second line with this: string `str2=@"sss"" + str1 + ""ddd";`

Comment: This does not output `sss" + str1 + "ddd`.

Comment: I thought in place of str1 you want a value of string str1 which you declared here

Comment: That's not what the OP asked for. I must say he's asked a weird question, but he's been quite specific.

Answer (score -3):

You may try this

```
string str1="xxx";
string str2=@"sss\"" + str1 + "\"ddd";
Console.WriteLine(str2);
```

**EDITED**

`string str1 = "\"xxx\"";
 string str2 = "sss" + str1 + "ddd";
 Console.WriteLine(str2);
 Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: This does not output `sss" + str1 + "ddd`.

Comment: @Enigmativity my bad, I missplace the quote. I had update my answer

Comment: Your edit outputs `sss"xxx"ddd` - that's not what the OP wants.

Comment: @Enigmativity, how you know that's is not what he want? He not even respond to each of the answer yet. By looking at his question, that is what the answer suppose to be. IMO

Comment: @Enigmativity My bad. I see, he want the "+" and double quotes included in the output. The question kinda confusing to me.