# SQS can't send only qutations messages in .Net core

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-sqs

I have some scenarios where I need to send messages with body:

> ""

When I try to do that using the following code:

```
var sqsClient= new AmazonSQSClient(new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKeyId","SecretKey"), new AmazonSQSConfig()
{
 ServiceURL ="https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/"
});
//obj value is "" and provided from user
var result = sqsClient.SendMessageAsync("queueURL", obj.ToString()).Result;
```

I get:

> {Amazon.SQS.AmazonSQSException: The request must contain the parameter
>   MessageBody. ---> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException:
>   Exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException'
>   was thrown.    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.HttpWebRequestMessage.d__20.MoveNext()
>   in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler_mobile\HttpRequestMessageFactory.cs:line
>   539
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
>   in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\HttpHandler.cs:line
>   175
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.d__3`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Amazon.SQS.Internal.ValidationResponseHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.d__5`1.MoveNext()
>
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext
>   executionContext, HttpErrorResponseException exception) in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.cs:line
>   60    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException(IExecutionContext
>   executionContext, Exception exception) in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler.cs:line
>   212    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext() in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler.cs:line
>   104
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.d__9`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.d__2`1.MoveNext()
>   in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\EndpointDiscoveryHandler.cs:line
>   79
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.<InvokeAsync>d__7`1.MoveNext()
>   in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CredentialsRetriever.cs:line
>   98
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.d__10`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
>   in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\RetryHandler\RetryHandler.cs:line
>   153
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.d__9`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.d__5`1.MoveNext()
>   in
>   E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\ErrorCallbackHandler.cs:line
>   58
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()}

However sending:

> " "

Works well!

Is there any workarrounds to send only

> ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you are trying to set the body to `""` but what you are actually doing is setting the body to the 0 byte empty string between the two `"`.  A string literal does not actually contain the quotes that surround it.  If *empty string* is what you actually want to send, that is not valid in SQS.

> the message body must not be empty or null.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-attributes.html

However, if you're actually trying to send two bytes of ASCII 0x22 `"` quote characters, those would need to appear and be [escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14480750/1695906) inside your string literal.

```
var result = sqsClient.SendMessageAsync("queueURL", "\"\"").Result;
```

*(Note that the citation from the SQS developer guide comes from a page concerned primarily with message atttibutes, but it does refer to the actual message body, not the message attributes, whose content is referred to as `Value`, not "body," and is mentioned separately as* also *not supporting empty or null.)*

Comment: Thanks for the hint. my compiller showed the value as "" so I could not guess that this is the issue, because it was like I receive an object containing the value "" and I convert it tostring