# how to declare xpath as a string variable? C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, xpath, escaping

How can I declare the following xpath value as a string variable in C#?

**Value:** `//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "lit-movie", " " ))]`

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480724/escape-double-quotes-in-string) helps you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape double quotes in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480724/escape-double-quotes-in-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use escape characters (use backslash), so `"` should be replaced by `\"`:

`string xpath = "//*[contains(concat( \" \", @class, \" \" ), concat( \" \", \"lit-movie\", \" \" ))]";`