# Smartsheet C# wrapper encoding character

Tags: smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

Is there any way to escape encoding of special character of the c# smartsheet api ?

likewise i would like to perform a search with double quotes:

```
https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/search?query="Previoo"
```

Although, on the implemtantation on the api the query is escaped:
https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-csharp-sdk/blob/master/main/Smartsheet/Api/Internal/SearchResourcesImpl.cs line 120 :

```
parameters.Add("query", Uri.EscapeDataString(query));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480724/escape-double-quotes-in-string) the quote characters in your query value and seeing your results?
It does look like the SDK is explicitly escaping the value given. I would open an [issue](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-csharp-sdk/issues) on the SDK and ask how this can be helped.

Comment: The quotes are being escaped by the C# wrapper. I need to force the wrapper to unescape the encoding. I'll send a pull request to the github repository.