# How to put quote (") in a string c#

Tags: c#

I want to print something like : Welcome "Aditya"

I tried using escape character

```
string s = "Welcome \"Aditya\"";
```

But it is printing as : Welcome \"Aditya\"

I have even tried to just print backslash(`\`) using  `string s = "\\"` but instead I got `\\`.

Can anyone help me understand why escape character is not working or if I am doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape double quotes in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480724/escape-double-quotes-in-string)

Comment: Your code `string s = "Welcome \"Aditya\"";` is correct; `Console.WriteLine(s);` should output `Welcome "Aditya"`.

Comment: I bet you're looking at it in the Watch window in Visual Studio. The Watch window will add backslashes for you. If you put `s,nq` in the watch window, it will stop doing this.

Comment: What other is the rest of your code? because this alone is not the problem

Comment: I have also tried `string s = @"Welcome ""Aditya"" "` but gives me the same output as I mentioned above.I am getting extra backslash before the quote

Comment: Like @canton7 said, you are probably looking at it in the watch window, and not in a console output (for example)

Comment: You are correct @canton7

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm guessing you're looking at the Watch window in Visual Studio:

[image: Watch Window Raw]

The Watch window adds its own quotes, and puts backslashes before any quotes in the string. This is probably confusing you.

You can click the magnifying glass next to the string in the watch window to see its actual value:

[image: Magnifying glass in watch window]

Alternatively, put `,nq` (for "no quotes") after the variable name:

[image: nq in watch window]

A full list of [Debugger Format specifiers is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-csharp?view=vs-2019).

If you're just hovering over the variable name, you can also click the magnifying glass to see the string's actual value:

[image: Magnifying glass in hover]

Answer (score 2):

Just use string literal:

```
string s = @"Welcome ""Aditya""";
```