# Replace the string concatenation in Migration script

Tags: c#, .net, string, c#-8.0

I am using below migration script to query against postgreSQL with EF core, for column names and table names i need to be enclosed with this symbol `" "`.

according to above condition i am writing the script like below, is there any way to escape the concatenation with `+` sign

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("UPDATE " + "\"" + "LibraryPipePlantTypes" + "\"" + " SET " + "\"" + "MasterSectionName" + "\"" + " = "+ "'" + "Library Pipe Plant Type" + "'" + " WHERE" + "\"" + "MasterSectionName" + "\"" + " = " + "'" + "Library Hydronic Plant Type" + "'");
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You've tried to write the string out with the escape character and no concats?  Like `"UPDATE \"LibraryPipePlantTypes\" SET"`?  Other discussion and examples on SO found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480724/escape-double-quotes-in-string).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using

```
migrationBuilder.Sql('UPDATE "LibraryPipePlantTypes" SET "MasterSectionName" = "Library Pipe Plant Type" WHERE "MasterSectionName" = "Library Hydronic Plant Type"');
```

Comment: Sadly, C# doesn't allow single-quotes for string literals.