# How to Replace quotes with double quotes in String.Replace?

Tags: c#, string, replace

I am trying to replace `'` with `"` but to no avail.

I have tried the following:

```
output = output.Replace(@"'", @""");

output = output.Replace("'", @""");

output = output.Replace(@"'", """);

output = output.Replace(@"'", """");
```

Comment: Note that if this is going to be applied to code (e.g. Javascript or Python) then char-per-char replacement will run into problems if the code itself contains escaped quotes or double quotes. To do a proper substitution in that case you need something more sophisticated (for example a regular expression).

Comment: Use the debugger's text visualizer feature, click on the spy glass.

Comment: Duplicate of [Escape double quotes in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480724/escape-double-quotes-in-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output = output.Replace("'", "\"");
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it and it include the backslash character as well

Comment: Then you're not using the proper characters, look at the fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1pLasS

Comment: this is so weird, I copied my code in the fiddle and the backslash \ doesn't show up, but it did in my code. hmmm

Answer (score 1):

You could use this piece of code, I have added a `\`

```
out = out.Replace("'","\"");
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it and it include the backslash character as well