# How to Construct a String If It Already Has " Inside

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I have a string which has `"` characters inside, I have tried using `''` to make it work but I get an erroe since I am trying to write that with streamwriter. I have checked some string formatting but couldn't find a way since using `''` gave an error.

My string:

```
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
```

My Code:

```
         using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(fileName))
        {
            sw.WriteLine('"<Invoice 
           xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"');

         }
```

I get a syntax error message saying "
Error   CS1012  Too many characters in character literal    " but when I check the error it seems it is about string being too long and I don't thing that is the case here

Comment: What error? What piece of code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480724/escape-double-quotes-in-string

Comment: What you're looking for is called "escaping". For example a proper string would be: `"Let's all say \"Hello, World!\""`.