# Make ' " ' as a symbol and not as a syntax

Tags: c#, regex

Goal:
Make the regex code to be working in C# code

Problem:
What syntax do I miss in order to make the regex code to be working in C#.
The regex code from https://regexr.com/578ul works but not at onelinegdb (https://www.onlinegdb.com/HycbSKxAL)

I have a symbol '"' that is part of the regex code but csharp consider it as a part of c# and not as a symbol.

---

Regex

```
,["0x465a27d8333756e1:0x66460f22856aea3b","broadway 22, 123 45 ny",null,[null,null,55.0359401,13.9717872]
,0,1]
```

C# code

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"","broad.*]";
        string input = @",["0x465a27d8333756e1:0x66460f22856aea3b","broadway 22, 123 45 ny",null,[null,null,55.0359401,13.9717872]
,0,1]"


        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Regex:
https://regexr.com/578ul

Onlinegdb with C# code:
https://www.onlinegdb.com/HycbSKxAL

Thank you!

Comment: Just escape it like `"\""` . Also I would be carefull with `]` character, as it's regex character used to denote character classes, so it should be escaped as well like `\]`

Comment: @MichałTurczyn it [seems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-escapes-in-regular-expressions#character-escapes-in-net) that only `[` needs to be escaped for single usage (unless `]` is used in `[]`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape double quotes in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480724/escape-double-quotes-in-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To escape `"` character in [verbatim string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) you can use another `"` character, so every occurrence of `""` inside it will be translated to single `"` character:

```
var str = @""""; // string consisting of one "
```

So your pattern will look like this:

```
string pattern = @""",""broad.*]";
```

And input:

```
string input = @",[""0x465a27d8333756e1:0x66460f22856aea3b"",""broadway 22, 123 45 ny"",null,[null,null,55.0359401,13.9717872]
,0,1]";
```

But in this particular case it seems that it will be easier to use simple string with `\` escape:

```
string pattern = "\",\"broad.*]";
```