# C# double " mark in textstring

Tags: c#, escaping

hi guys I made an app to extract .lua file when I push the button
my problem is I need to pass this string like this

```
QUESTID = LuaGetQuestID("QNO_QUEST_AR")
```

QNO_QUEST_AR extracted from textBox1 so my code =

```
            File.Write("  QUESTID = LuaGetQuestID("+textBox1.Text+")\r\n");
```

I need to add 2x " mark like this (""+textBox1.Text+"")
anyway to do that ? thanks

Comment: You can escape the double-quote like so: `\"`. Or you can use literal strings (strings starting with `@`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape double quotes in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480724/escape-double-quotes-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a 'verbatim identifier' (`@`) and escape quotes with double quotes.

Note that you can also combine the 'string interpolation identifier' (`$`) so that you're not building up the string with pluses. See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Then you could write your code something like:

```
var myString = @$"QUESTID = LuaGetQuestID(""{textBox1.Text}"")";
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks, guys it works with this code

```
File.Write("  QUESTID = LuaGetQuestID(" + '"' + textBox1.Text + '"' + ")\r\n");
```