# I need to insert a "" inside another ""

Tags: c++, string, bash

I'm trying to use bash commands from inside a c++ application; which also have strings inside the bash command, and when I try to compile... the compiler sees the line as two separate string next to each other. 
Look at the following code:

```
const char* command = "echo -e "\e[31mHello World\e[0m""
```

How do I insert the string that echo reads -inside the string that echo itself is in?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 because it's tricky to google this if you don't know the right words to use.

Comment: @djechlin `bash put quotes inside quotes` gives me a stackoverflow question on escaping as a first result.

Comment: @remyabel case in point.

Comment: @djechlin But the question title isn't "put quotes inside quotes" is it? :P

Comment: @remyabel it's not. When I have to google things about punctuation marks it often takes me an annoying number of tries to get something relevant. So I would expect more SO questions that haven't been closed as duplicate on topics like this than others. I put myself in the shoes of the OP and could see myself getting stuck, without having experience in trying a bunch of synonyms.

Comment: @remyabel posted another answer along those lines

Comment: Doesn't C allow single-quoted strings as well as double-quoted strings?  If no, why not just use `const char* command = 'echo -e "\e[31mHello World\e[0m"';`?

Answer (score 8):

The term you are looking for is "escaping." Escape `"` by putting a `\` in front of it.

```
const char* command = "echo -e \"\e[31mHello World\e[0m\""
```

Many languages use this solution. Put a backslash in front of a special character to deactivate its special meaning and interpret it as text. This is called escaping.

Answer (score 1):

I answered your question specifically, but I want to post a completely different approach to this problem:

Your original title was something like

> I need to insert a """ inside another """

Googling that does not help. But adding "C++" and changing it to:

> I need to insert a quote inside another quote C++

Gives many many answers, e.g.

[How to get double quotes into a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338818/how-to-get-double-quotes-into-a-string-literal)

So: **your problem solving should first include trying all the different ways to say the punctuation as possible.** "Quote," "Double quote, "apostrophe" (wrong but who cares?), etc. should all come first. Then try things like "string around string" and so forth. This is a general strategy for this type of problem.