# Input double quotes in C++ 98

Tags: c++, stl

I have gone through other StackOverflow questions but what i need is little different. 
I have a long string (probable from some word document) and i want to count the number of characters of the string.
I am copying that long string in my code `string s3=<paste the string here>` How do i proceed ahead. I dont need a solution in C++11.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string s1="My test"; //Works
    string s2="My" "test"; //Still works
    string s3="My"1003"test"; //Doest work. My string being input from user is `My "1003" test`. If i input it in string it becomes "My "1003" test.
    cout<<s;
}
```

**Edit** : Read the question first adn try to understand what is the catch here instead of blindly suggesting as duplicate. Escaping the character is not handy as the string might comtain a lot of doublw quotes and manually using escape character for double quotes is not handy.

Comment: How are you reading the string? Post a complete example that actually compiles.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get double quotes into a string literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338818/how-to-get-double-quotes-into-a-string-literal)

Comment: Double quote is just a regular single-byte character, I don't see any reason to have issues with in on the input.

Comment: Is this about strings that are entered by the user during runtime or about string litterals in your sourcecode? Escaping is only necessary for string litterals in your sourcecode

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enter a string in your source code that has a `"` in it, you need to escape it as `\"`.

Example: `"My\"1003\"test"` is a string containing the letter 'M', the letter 'y', a quotation mark, the digit 1, and so on.

Comment: Sure. But if the string is long and it has many such double quotes, its not good to manually type "\" before every double quote.

Comment: @anurag86 Use your favourite find-and-replace tool, then.