# How to print QString in quots

Tags: qt, qt4

I want to print the value in QSting inside Quots

```
QString data = "Hello";
QMessageBox::warning(NULL, "Job", "Already data" + data+ " exist");
```

I want the message to be :-  Already data "Hello" exist

Comment: Maybe `QMessageBox::warning(NULL, "Job", "Already data\"" + data+ "\" exist");`?

Comment: Use: `QString data = "Hello";
    QMessageBox::warning(NULL, "Job", QString("Already data \"%1\" exist").arg(data));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get double quotes into a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338818/how-to-get-double-quotes-into-a-string-literal)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you most use backslash before quots

Here's an example of how you'd use this feature:

```
QMessageBox::warning(NULL, "Job", "Already data\"" + data+ "\" exist");
```