# C++ : Trigger a python script stored on my machine, from inside a C++ script

Tags: c++

I would like to trigger a python script from my C++ script. The python script is independent, I do not need to pass it anything from C++, I also do not need anything returned to C++.

I would also like to pause execution of the C++ script until the python script has finished.

I have tried the embedding solutions and the wrapping solutions offered online, but I am looking for something much simpler.

I have attempted the following.

```
include cstdlib
system("py "C:\path\python_script.py"");
```

This attempt has problems with the double quotation mark syntax.
I then attempted this to deal with the double quotation mark probem.

```
include cstdlib
system("py " + char(34) + "C:\path\python_script.py" + char(34));
```

I then received the error "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type". It seems as though you can't concatenate strings this way in C++?
For my final attempt, I tried to concatenate the string in pieces.

```
include cstdlib
string   path1 = "py ";
string   path2 = "C:\path\python_script.py";
string   path = python_path1 + char(34) + python_path2 + char(34);
system(path);
```

I now receive the error "no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "const char" exists".
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with python. Remove the python tag

Comment: The last example, where you use std::string will work if you pass the argument as `path.c_str()`. This returns the `std::string`'s `const char*` representation.

Answer (score 2):

As other answer tell you add \ to escape the " and also double escape your \ path separator  :

```
system("py \"C:\\path\\python_script.py\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `system("py \"C:\path\python_script.py\"");`.

This way you escape the quotation mark and can write it into a string.

[Have a look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338818/how-to-get-double-quotes-into-a-string-literal)

Answer (score 0):

Try string stream

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream ss;
ss << "py ";
ss << "\"C:\path\python_script.py\"";
system(ss.str().c_str());
```

Comment: stringstream is overkill for a problem that can simply be solved by character escaping...