# Backslashes and quotes not getting counted to string length?

Tags: c++, json

I got JSON written in String. The length in Notepad++ shows 210 characters, but in C+++ only 182.

How do I get 210 characters in C++?

Example JSON with Escape quotes:

```
{\"_id\":\"5de2dff0d6c9e312d659bc42\",\"index\":\"0\",\"guid\":\"eba0e936-0b18-48ec-88ca-00312ede4a7d\",\"isActive\":\"false\",\"balance\":\"$1,636.50\",\"picture\":\"http://placehold.it/32x32\",\"age\":\"36\"}
```

And my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //210 characters
    string str = "{\"_id\":\"5de2dff0d6c9e312d659bc42\",\"index\":\"0\",\"guid\":\"eba0e936-0b18-48ec-88ca-00312ede4a7d\",\"isActive\":\"false\",\"balance\":\"$1,636.50\",\"picture\":\"http://placehold.it/32x32\",\"age\":\"36\"}";
    cout << "String Length = " << str.length(); // return 182
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pop quiz: `\"` is two characters, according to Notepad. Your pop quiz: how many characters is that, according to C++, when used as part of a quoted string literal, as is the case in your code? Free clue: it's not two characters.

Comment: How is this related to the ESP 32 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth combo chip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every [`\"` ends up not being two different characters, but just one `"` character](http://gillius.org/ctut/app_a.htm), that's why the character count seems to be off. The reason for this is that double quotes in a string literal [need to be escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12338818/9835872).

You can use a [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) to hold this string, because every `\` will then just be taken as a literal backslash character in them, and thus every `\"` will just mean a backslash + a double quote:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = R"({\"_id\":\"5de2dff0d6c9e312d659bc42\",\"index\":\"0\",\"guid\":\"eba0e936-0b18-48ec-88ca-00312ede4a7d\",\"isActive\":\"false\",\"balance\":\"$1,636.50\",\"picture\":\"http://placehold.it/32x32\",\"age\":\"36\"})";
    cout << "String Length = " << str.length();
    return 0;
}
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> String Length = 210
> ```